# Rails Redirect URL adding ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

iam using a redirect in one of my classes, however iam a bit confused about the URL which is send back to the User.

After my user is logged in, he is redirect as following:

```
redirect_to :controller => "mycontroller", :action => "myaction"
```

When I look at the URL which is send back, i see the following:

```
http://l1vmgt08:8085/mycontroller/myaction/id
```

Due to the "id" in the URL, I had to add it also in my routes, including the "id":

```
match "mycontroller/myaction/id", :to => "mycontroller#myaction", :via => :get
```

I dont get why the redirect adds the "id" to the URL. I guess this is a rails default, but i dont understand where the benefit of this is. Since i just want to perform the action, i do not need an id, and there is none provided..

I guess iam missing a critical point about how routing works, but I dont find any additional informations which explain that behavior..

Thanks in advance :)

edit:

here is the login action:

```
def login_attempt
authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username_or_email],params[:login_password])
if authorized_user
  session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
  redirect_to :controller => "webqipparser", :action => "parser_formular"

else
  render "login"
end
```

end

Comment: Read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: i have already done that, however I dont find an answer to my question. Maybe i just dont see the connection between the explanations and need someone to point it out.. I would be really thankful if someone could do so

Comment: Could you paste the code of the action that handles login of users ?

Comment: added it above.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues fixed it. The solution is to not redirect to a controller/action, but to a path, since I just want to render the view..

```
redirect_to controller_view_path
```